# "Google Maps is tracking your location" blue status bar

Tags: ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios

Have a strange bug, we use Google Maps SDK in our iOS app and ever since iOS 8.3 we have been getting the annoying "Google Maps is tracking your locaton" blue flashing status bar **when we launch our app**. It doesn't always happen though, it seem random. Has anyone else run into this? If so, have you found a way to prevent this from happening?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Haven't seen this in iOS 8.4 so I am going to assume this was a bug in the OS.

Comment: When your location service updated location, did you call `stopUpdatingLocation` method?

Comment: Yes, this actually happens before I even call the google maps api

Comment: can you post some code snippets? I never saw this problem in my app using Google maps. I notice the official google maps app shows this blue bar though.

Comment: There really isn't any code to post. It happens as soon as the app launches. The only thing being called is the "[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"myKeyGoesHere"]" in the appDelegate. It doesn't happen all the time either. I wonder if it's an iOS bug.

Comment: I never saw this problem on all my apps using Google Maps SDK. I saw the blur bar when I exit the official Google Maps app on my phone though. Maybe did you enable the background location service?

Comment: why do you think that is a bug? just because it is __not__. if the _Google Maps_ runs in background and request updates about your location usually that bar appears at the top of the screen to notify the user about a background app still tracks their movement; but every application can invoke that bar if the location-tracking is running in the background by a certain app.

Comment: @holex read the other comments, it was happening at launch of the app before any calls were made to the Google SDK. The app was NOT being put into the background, the app was in the foreground.